# Conditionally Disable Validation in Model Partial Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, attributes, partial-classes

I have a partial class with validation attributes -

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(tblPersonMetadata))]
public partial class tblPerson
{
}

public class tblPersonMetadata
{
   [MaxLength(80)]
   public string PER_MiddleName { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your Gender")]
   public string PER_Gender { get; set; }
}
```

The tblPerson is an entity in Entity Framework used in multiple locations.  In some locations, I want to leave PER_MiddleName and PER_Gender empty.

How can I selectively disable the validation when tblPerson is used in some objects?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is that I need an attribute library to handle [RequiredIf()].  I got a good one - https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations.  It works to my satisfaction.